# How to set inputmask when Angular generete the control in row

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular table that create rows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows" class="gridRow">
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtCompanyTitle" class="form-control" ng-model="CompanyTitle" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtCompanyTaxes" class="form-control currencyMask" ng-model="CompanyTaxes" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="deleteRow(rowContent)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
<tr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addRow()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</button>
```

I need to set the mask of the txtCompanyTaxes using:

```
$(".currencyMask").inputmask('currency', {
    prefix: '',
    groupSeparator: '@Global.Mask_NumberGroupSeparetor',
    radixPoint: '@Global.Mask_NumberRadixPoint',
    autoGroup: true
});
```

I did try this below, but it just work on the current row when I create the next row (the last row never gets the mask):

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])

    myApp.controller('Companies', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.rows = ['Row 1'];
        $scope.counter = 2;

        $scope.addRow = function () {
            $scope.rows.push('Row ' + $scope.counter);
            $scope.counter++;
            $(".currencyMask").inputmask('currency', {
                prefix: '',
                groupSeparator: '@Global.Mask_NumberGroupSeparetor',
                radixPoint: '@Global.Mask_NumberRadixPoint',
                autoGroup: true
            });
        }

        $scope.deleteRow = function (item) {
            if (confirm("@Global.Form_AreYouSure")) {
                var index = $scope.rows.indexOf(item);
                $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

Comment: It would be better to create a directive for `currencyMask`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Satpal,

I did found a directive to do that here:

http://valve.github.io/blog/2013/08/01/jquery-inputmask-plugin-plus-angularjs/